# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 | "You have already authorized YOUR_APP" appears every time user tries to login

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm currently trying to implement the Facebook-Login-Flow with iOS Facebook SDK 3.1.
But there is a little Problem with it. Every time the user logs in with facebook the webview will open up and says

> "You have already authorized YOUR_APP.."

The code I wrote based on the following example: [click here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/) 
Now my question is, how can I avoid this behaviour and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please see this code ,it may help

```
    postParams=
    [@{
       @"link" :link,
       @"picture" :picture link , //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",KBaseImageUrl,@"/assets/img/logo-small.jpg"],
       @"name" : @“name”,
       @"caption" : caption title,
       @"description" :discription
       } mutableCopy];
    title=[[arrayEventInfo valueForKey:@"info"] valueForKey:@"eventname"];


if ([[FBSession activeSession]isOpen])
{

    if ([[[FBSession activeSession]permissions]indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound)
    {

        [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_action"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,NSError *error){

                                                      // If permissions granted, publish the story
                                                      [FBRequestConnection
                                                       startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                                       parameters:postParams
                                                       HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                                       completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                           id result,
                                                                           NSError *error)
                                                       {
                                                           NSString *alertText;
                                                           if (error)
                                                           {
                                                               alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                                            @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                                                                            error.domain, error.code];
                                                           }
                                                           else
                                                           {
                                                               alertText = @"Posted successfully on your wall.";//[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                               //@"Posted action, id: %@",
                                                               // result[@"id"]];
                                                           }
                                                           //Show the result in an alert
                                                           [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                                                       message:alertText
                                                                                      delegate:self
                                                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
                                                           [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                                                           [FBSession.activeSession close];


                                                       }];

                                                      UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=(UIActivityIndicatorView*)[self.view viewWithTag:111];
                                                      if(activityView)
                                                      {
                                                          [activityView removeFromSuperview];
                                                      }
                                                      [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                                                      [self.navigationController.navigationBar setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];




                                              }];

    }else
    {

            // If permissions granted, publish the story
            [FBRequestConnection
             startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
             parameters:postParams
             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
             completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                 id result,
                                 NSError *error)
             {
                 NSString *alertText;
                 if (error)
                 {
                     alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                  @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                                  error.domain, error.code];
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     alertText = @"Posted successfully on your wall.";//[NSString stringWithFormat:
                     //@"Posted action, id: %@",
                     // result[@"id"]];
                 }
                 //Show the result in an alert
                 [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                             message:alertText
                                            delegate:self
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
                 [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                 [FBSession.activeSession close];


             }];


    }
}
else
{


    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                       defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                         if (!error && status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
                                             if (!error)
                                             {
                                                 // If permissions granted, publish the story
                                                 [FBRequestConnection
                                                  startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                                  parameters:postParams
                                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                                  completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                      id result,
                                                                      NSError *error)
                                                  {
                                                      NSString *alertText;
                                                      if (error)
                                                      {
                                                          alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                                       @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                                                                       error.domain, error.code];
                                                      }
                                                      else
                                                      {
                                                          alertText = @"Posted successfully on your wall.";//[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                          //@"Posted action, id: %@",
                                                          // result[@"id"]];
                                                      }
                                                      //Show the result in an alert
                                                      [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                                                  message:alertText
                                                                                 delegate:self
                                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
                                                      [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                                                      [FBSession.activeSession close];


                                                  }];

                                             }
                                         }else{
                                             NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
                                             UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=(UIActivityIndicatorView*)[self.view viewWithTag:111];
                                             if(activityView)
                                             {
                                                 [activityView removeFromSuperview];
                                             }
                                             [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                                             [self.navigationController.navigationBar setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

                                         }
                                     }];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are testing the code in dev then the first time you log in it will store that session on Facebook.

So, you try to test it again but it is already authorized.

If you want to test the login process again then go to Facebook and de-authorize your app (it will be in your list of apps).

Then you can log in again on the device.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the answer to my question. The Login Process works fine. I just dont want to show the "you have already authorized YOUR_APP" screen everytime after pressing the Facebook-Loginbutton.

Comment: If the user is already logged in then they shouldn't be pressing the "login" button. They should go through the login process straight to the "meat" of the app. If they see a Facebook button it should say "Logout".

Comment: I think you dont understand what my problem is : 1. The user logs in the first time with facebook,accepts the permissions. 2. The user clicks the logout action , token gets cleared . 3. User will login --> here he clicks again on the facebook button , but now the "authorization screen" should not appear. Cause he allready authorized the app.

Comment: Ah, I see. But I think you are mistaken. After you log out it removes any knowledge of the Facebook status from the app. When you then login again it will go through the FB authorisation process but the user won't have to press "Authorize this app" and so they see the "This app is already authorized" screen. Try it with another "non facebook" app.

Comment: Echoing Fogmeister, the user sees this screen if they had previously authorized the app - AND - they are being authorized with a webview or mobile Safari. For native iOS6 login and authorizations against Facebook iOS native app, they do not see this screen. This is by design.

Comment: @Fogmeister I am facing the same problem, Have you fixed this ??

Comment: @NithinMK this isn't a problem. There is nothing wrong with this behaviour.

Comment: @Fogmeister but in some of other apps don't show that screen again.
Will our apps also hide the screen any days in future ?
is it an FB issue ??

Comment: I'd suggest making sure you have the latest SDK and follow the Facebook tutorials first. This is a very old question. The FB SDKs have all be updated since this was asked.

Comment: yea I have the very latest SDK with me